# Vim NERDTree colors

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I want to change default blue color of folders

[image]

How to set it?

Comment: look in the helpfiles for nerdtree, I believe it's listed there...

Comment: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree$ grep -r "color" *
~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree$ grep -r "cterm" *
~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree$ grep -r "guiterm" *  - no results :(

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
:hi Directory guifg=#FF0000 ctermfg=red
```

Comment: How do you change the color of the "expand" icons (basically the + signs)

Comment: @gosukiwi There are two highlight groups for NERDTree "expand" sign, so basically Change "Directory" in the above command to "NERDTreeClosable" and "NERDTreeOpenable"

Comment: how can i use this in my .vimrc? i need to set this command every time i open vim

Comment: @CarlosMartinez put the above in the .vimrc and it will work

Answer (score 4):

If you want to customize file colors based on extension, I created [this plugin](https://github.com/tiagofumo/vim-nerdtree-syntax-highlight). You can use it with [vim-devicons](https://github.com/ryanoasis/vim-devicons), but If you don't have it, you can add this line to your .vimrc and it will highlight the filenames:

```
let g:NERDTreeFileExtensionHighlightFullName = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a heavy vim user, but, I think you can add the following to your `.vimrc` to highlight the folders/directories in Cyan

`highlight Directory ctermfg=cyan`

Have only tried this out in MacOS 10.14

Comment: Works in "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7' as well

Answer (score 0):

NERDTree doesn't provide such an option but looking at the [source](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/plugin/NERD_tree.vim#L3416-3504) 
 and reading about [highlight](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/#%3ahighlight) you could come up with some customization.